# X11 Forwarding to OSX

Tags: x11-forwarding

I've successfully installed and enabled X11 forwarding.. according to these instructions.

http://forrestbao.blogspot.com/2008/01/connecting-your-remote-linux-desktop.html

I first tried to connect via

```
 > ssh -X <username@ipaddress>

  > gnome-session
```

I get

```
  > ** (gnome-session:4640): WARNING **: Cannot open display:
```

Later I found a suggestion to try

```
 > ssh -XC <username@ipaddress>

 > gnome-session
```

I was seeing a screen, but the unity menu that normally appears on the left was not visible.

I am unclear what's wrong here, but will attempt to restart the system in a minute.  I have full root access and retried with sudo.  Nothing changed.

Comment: @LiveWireBT You do not need to be a jackass with your comments, please be nice to users and use a more proper way of addressing them...

Comment: I was successful using Xquartz client and the flags >ssh -XC <username@ipaddress> .. However gnomes side menu isnt showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

before running the command `gnome-session` .

I see that the OP was able to solve this a different way :

> I was successful using Xquartz client and the flags >ssh -XC
>    .. However gnome's side menu isn't showing.

Comment: Any idea why ssh -XC worked ?